# Creating Multiple Excel worksheets in a workbook from an SQLserver 2008 table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, export-to-excel

This is my first time on this forum.  I will do my best to describe my question.

I have a table in my database called SerialExtract that has 4 fields.   Productnumber, serialnumber, Constraint, Volume.   What I need to do for my customer is load this data into an Excel workbook - where there is a tab (worksheet) for each Productnumber in my table, and the associated data for that product on that tab.   The tabs need to be dynamic (since the productnumbers will change) - so that each time I run the load it refreshes the excel workbook.

Any suggestions on what type of tool I should use to accomplish this?   My initial thoughts were to use SSIS or write a SPROC in SqlServer that can write to the Excel workbook.  I can loop through the data by product - just not sure how to write to Excel with different tabs based on data.

thanks!

Barb

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, there is a built-in feature to query data from a SQL server and to get the data loaded into an Excel spreadsheet. Side note, you can do this dynamic connection from various external sources, not only for SQL Server.

Simply use this feature by defining this query in each spreadsheet of your workbook. Here is a screenshot where you can find the option in Excel 2010.

[image]